# Axon external event handler not working and table not being created

Tags: spring, kotlin, axon

i'm new to axon. i want to make simple axon app.

i'm

1. using two instances (command app, query app)
2. using axon server
3. using kotlin
4. using multi-module
5. axon framework 4.5

and i checked command app that storing event data from dashboard(http://localhost:8024)

However, event handler not invoked

here is project structure

```
practice-root
│
├── command
│   ├── build
│   ├── src
│   │    ├── main
│   │    │     ├ kotlin
│   │    │     │  └ com.cqrs.axon
│   │    │     │         ├ Application.kt
│   │    │     │         ├ SimpleDTO
│   │    │     │         ├ SimpleController
│   │    │     │         ...
│   │    │     └ resources
│   │    ├── test
│   │    │
│   └── build.gradle
│
├── query
│     ├ ...
│     ...
│
├── README
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

here is my code

**command module**

Application.kt

```
@SpringBootApplication()
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

SimpleService.kt

```
@Service
class SimpleService(
    private val eventGateway: EventGateway
) {
    @CommandHandler
    fun createSimple(simpleDTO: SimpleDTO): Unit {
        return this.eventGateway.publish(
            SimpleEvent(
                id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                data = simpleDTO.data
            )
        )
    }
}
```

SimpleDTO.kt

```
data class SimpleDTO (
    val data: String
)
```

SimpleController.kt

```
@RestController
class SimpleController(
    private val simpleService: SimpleService
    ) {

    @PostMapping("/simple")
    fun createSimple(@RequestBody simpleDTO: SimpleDTO): Unit {
        return simpleService.createSimple(simpleDTO)
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
---
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: commandSpringApplication
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/test?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true
    username: userA
    password: u123

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
        ddl-auto: update
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

axon:
  serializer:
    general: xstream
  axonserver:
    servers: localhost:8124

logging:
  level:
    com:
      cqrs:
        command: debug
    org:
      axonframework: debug
```

**query module**

Application.kt

```
@SpringBootApplication()
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

QuerySimpleProjection.kt

```
@Component
class QuerySimpleProjection (
    private val simpleRepository: QuerySimpleRepository
) {

    @EventHandler
    fun on(event: SimpleEvent, @Timestamp instant: Instant) {
        val simpleMV = SimpleMV(
            id = event.id,
            data = event.data
        )
        simpleRepository.save(simpleMV)
    }
}
```

QuerySimpleRepository.kt

```
@Repository
interface QuerySimpleRepository : JpaRepository<SimpleMV, String>
```

SimpleMV.kt

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mv_simple")
data class SimpleMV (

    @Id
    val id: String,
    val data: String
)
```

AxonConfig.kt

```
@Configuration
class AxonConfig {

    @Autowired
    fun configureProcessorDefault(processingConfigurer: EventProcessingConfigurer) {
        processingConfigurer.usingSubscribingEventProcessors()
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
---
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  application:
    name: querySpringApplication
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/test?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf8&useUnicode=true
    username: userA
    password: u123

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
        ddl-auto: create
        format_sql: true
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC

axon:
  serializer:
    general: xstream
  axonserver:
    servers: localhost:8124


logging:
  level:
    com:
      cqrs:
        command: debug
    org:
      axonframework: debug
```

**common module**

SimpleEvent.kt

```
data class SimpleEvent (
    val id: String,
    val data: String
)
```

build.gradle of command module and query module

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-jpa'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
...
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation "org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter:4.5.8"
    implementation "org.axonframework:axon-configuration:4.5.8"
    implementation "org.axonframework:axon-server-connector:4.5.8"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I thought that the event would be stored in the command module
and data would be included in the mv_simple table of the query module.
The table was not created either.

What should I do to make it work?

---

[update]

i change to this

```
 spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
      ...
```

now i can see tables that created.
but still can't store data to mv_simple table.

eventhandler isn't invoked

Comment: Spring boot may not automatically find your entities and therefore not create the necessary tables. What are the package names for each of those classes?

Comment: query and command app's package names are `com.cqrs.axon`.
i use SimpleEvent.kt from common module. common module's package name is  `com.cqrs.common`.
so i changed to `com.cqrs.axon` than it works!! thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: Note that the original issue isn’t Axon related, but rather related to Spring Boot Autoconfiguration. It only scans packages relative to the package of the Application class. Either same package or subpackages

Comment: thank you to reply!! is it impossible to use different package names? should every services have same names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change common package names to com.cqrs.axon.
it's impotant to use same package names!
it works after removing Axonconfig.kt to use Tracking Event Processor in above code.